# Why I can't access a form object inside a ngInclude on angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-include

I have a screen built with a several stacks of ng-includes. The last one, in special, I build the screen based on user configuration.

Sometimes, I have to show a Form in one of this included templates. And when my user click on save button, I have to validate if all fields in the form are valid.

In the meantime, when a try to access form object, to check for $valid, my form is undefined.

After a day fighting against it, I've discovered that ng-include process is not accepting my form object to be created.

I've created this plunker to see if it's really happening on a simple project, making a working form and not working one:
http://plnkr.co/edit/4oMZYLgaYHJPoSZdSctI?p=preview

Basically, created a form, like this, with demanded angular attributes:

```
<form name="sampleForm">
    <input type="text" name="aws" required ng-model="myValue">
    <br/>myValue: "{{ myValue }}"
    <br/>

    <input type="text" name="aws" required ng-model="myValue">
    <br/>myValue: "{{ myValue }}"
</form>
```

And trying to access form object like this:

```
$scope.sampleForm.aws.$valid
```

And the result is:

```
$scope.sampleForm === undefined
```

Someone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `ng-include` creates a new scope, `$scope.sampleForm` will be undefined from within the included page.

The solution should be getting the `ng-controller="formController"` declaration inside of the included HTML page itself, which I think is also a better design, since I can't see a scenario where it's not "controlling" the form.

The other non-included form obviously works as you might expect.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/f5tB8KUVNio8awidWYMY?p=preview)

Comment: Yes. The code I've made on Plunker is a little naive compared to my real solution. On my case, 'formController' is something more generic, like: RegistrationController and it still controlling things outside this form. Do you suggest to create another controller to it?

Comment: @DiegoLaucsen Yes, I suggest that :)

Comment: Working!! Tks for help.